# angular-cli tests debugging

Tags: debugging, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm building a project using angular2-cli. When I run ng test, karma fires up my chrome browser. I click the debug button in the upper right corner and I open up the console.

How can I set up break points in the files that are being tested? I know how to set up break points in the test files but it doesn't really help here since I'm stuck going into endless jasmine functions and methods.

Say the test invokes the method on my component. Is it possible to set up the break point which takes me directly to the component when the test is being run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured out how to solve it.

I couldn't set any breakpoints inside my non-test code, because the sourced map code was only available for the test files.

My problem was the duplicate of this [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1798),
which was closed in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1799).

The commit was merged to master in **angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.19.3.**

So to allow for debbuging the source code when running tests you need to do the following:

1. Update angular-cli to version angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.19.3 or higher

   `npm uninstall angular-cli
   npm cache clean
   npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.19.3`
2. Run `ng -v` to confirm you are on 1.0.0-beta.19.3. (Do it outside the current angular-cli project you are working on, or it will show to local version)
3. Update the package.json of your current project to use newly installed cli:

   `"devDependencies": {
   "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.19-3",
   }`
4. Run `npm update --save-dev`
5. Run `ng test` - happy debugging!